# Publicidad NO intencional en código de ejemplo: ¿debemos dejarla o no?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Hace menos de semana me crucé con una pregunta. Al responderla usé la herramienta para que puedan ejecutar el código de ejemplo. Entonces noté que los mismos enlaces que el OP proveía eran anuncios publicitarios (supuse que el problema era precisamente al momento de visualizar los anuncios en su página web).

La duda estaba en dejar el código de mi respuesta tal como está para que simplemente le dieran *Ejecutar* y vieran como funcionaba, pero eso implicaba visualizar los anuncios publicitarios. Opté por cambiar algunas letras de las url al azar para evitar verlos. Pero la pregunta es...

**¿Hubiera sido correcto si dejaba las URL de publicidad intactas en mi respuesta?**

Si lo dejaba era para un mejor entendimiento del OP, pero a costa de la promoción de un producto o servicio (publicidad no autorizada).

Comment: Dejo la URL por si las dudas:    https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302932/recorrer-un-json-con-javascript-y-pintar-datos-aleatorios/302939#302939

Comment: Fácil: modifica las URL (o al menos el dominio principal) por uno cualquiera, tipo ejemplo.com. Acabo de hacerlo.

Comment: Vi tu edición, y no me refería a eso sino a que para usar los fragmentos de HTML y Javascript con el snipet y correr el código en el sitio es donde implica usar la publicidad... mientras no se utilice esa herramienta los enlaces no suponen ningun problema, es mas, son totalmente necesarios para poder reproducir el error/falla/problema fuera del sitio... Con la edición que hiciste puede verse implicada la misma pregunta ya que modificaste el código del OP y como no hizo uso de los fragmentos de HTML y Javascript el código no se ejecuta y por ende la publicidad no se vería reflejada en el sitio.

Comment: Ajá, ya veo. De todos modos, el usuario simplemente necesita iterar sobre un JSON con una lista de diccionarios e imprimir los valores de algunos de los elementos de cada diccionario. Por tanto, y en mi opinión, a efectos del resultado no es necesario que los datos sean "reales". Distinto sería que tuviera que conectar con una API concreta, para lo cual la llamada no podría hacerse con una URL "codificada".

Comment: En lo personal, se debe mantener los datos de manera anónima, como dominios, inclusive endpoints, nombres de usuarios/contraseñas. Ha existido preguntas con datos hasta de clientes de la empresa donde trabaja el OP...

Comment: También vi algunos casos en preguntas de firebase y angular en el que mostraba todos los datos para la conexión en su archivo environments, pero supongo todo depende de la sensibilidad de los mismos datos

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado en ese caso reporta la pregunta y/o editala